# Text node not displaying on screen

Tags: arrays, javascript-objects

I'm attempting to loop through an array of objects and display the results dynamically on the screen in some input fields
It seemed to be going well until I was creating a text node to put into the input tag. It will create the node and the console and elements tab recognizes the text node but it wont display on the screen.
I'm also getting an extra input with undefined text. Any help at all will be greatly appreciated!

```js
var questions = [

  {
    one: "In which HTML element do we put in Javascript code?",
    choices1: ['<js>', '<script>', '<body>', '<link>']
  },
  {
    2: 'Which HTML attribute is used to reference an external Javascript file?',
    choices2: ['src', 'rel', 'type', 'href']
  },
  {
    3: 'How would you write "Hello" in an alert box?',
    choices3: ['msg("Hello")', 'alertBox("Hello")', 'document.write("Hello")', 'alert("Hello")']
  },
  {
    4: 'Javascript is directly related the the "Java" programming language',
    choices4: ['true', 'false']
  },
  {
    5: "A variable in Javascript must start with which special character",
    choices5: ['@', '$', '#', 'No Special Character']
  }

]

var h3Q1 = document.querySelector('.q1');

h3Q1.innerHTML = questions[0].one;
var br = '<br>';


var form = document.querySelector('[name=quizForm]');

for (var i = 0; i <= questions[0].choices1.length; i++) {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(questions[0].choices1[i]);
  input.type = 'radio';
  input.name = 'q1';
  input.value = 'a';
  input.id = 'q1a';
  input.appendChild(textNode);
  form.insertBefore(input, form[0]);
  input.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', br);

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Javascript Quiz</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Simple Javascript Quiz</h1>
      <p>Test your knowledge in <strong>Javascript fundamentals</strong></p>
    </header>
    <section>
      <div id="results"></div>

      <form name="quizForm" onsubmit="return submitAnswers()">
        <h3 class="q1"></h3>

        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit Answers">



      </form>
    </section>
  </div>



  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add a textNode (or any other HTML for what it matters) to an input element. Best thing to do is use a label and place the input and textnode inside this. It has the added benefit of the input getting selected when you click on the text.

```js
var questions = [

  {
    one: "In which HTML element do we put in Javascript code?",
    choices1: ['<js>', '<script>', '<body>', '<link>']
  },
  {
    2: 'Which HTML attribute is used to reference an external Javascript file?',
    choices2: ['src', 'rel', 'type', 'href']
  },
  {
    3: 'How would you write "Hello" in an alert box?',
    choices3: ['msg("Hello")', 'alertBox("Hello")', 'document.write("Hello")', 'alert("Hello")']
  },
  {
    4: 'Javascript is directly related the the "Java" programming language',
    choices4: ['true', 'false']
  },
  {
    5: "A variable in Javascript must start with which special character",
    choices5: ['@', '$', '#', 'No Special Character']
  }

]

var h3Q1 = document.querySelector('.q1');

h3Q1.innerHTML = questions[0].one;
var br = '<br>';


var form = document.querySelector('[name=quizForm]'),
    button = form.querySelector('.submit');

for (var i = 0; i <= questions[0].choices1.length; i++) {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  var label = document.createElement('label');
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(questions[0].choices1[i]);
  input.type = 'radio';
  input.name = 'q1';
  input.value = 'a';
  input.id = 'q1a';
  label.append(input);
  label.appendChild(textNode);  
  form.insertBefore(label, button);
  label.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', br);

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Javascript Quiz</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Simple Javascript Quiz</h1>
      <p>Test your knowledge in <strong>Javascript fundamentals</strong></p>
    </header>
    <section>
      <div id="results"></div>

      <form name="quizForm" onsubmit="return submitAnswers()">
        <h3 class="q1"></h3>

        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit Answers">



      </form>
    </section>
  </div>



  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```